# How to proper setting root mysql password

Tags: mojave, homebrew, mysql

I'm trying to make Mysql and phpMyAdmin works.

I installed mysql using `brew`

Following those answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6474775/setting-the-mysql-root-user-password-on-os-x

I tried to set a plain text password

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string='root' WHERE User='root';
```

But now when I try to login into phpmyadmin I get 2 errors (I'm not able to connect even with `mysql` cli with "Access denied" error):

```
 mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]


 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
```

Comment: Have you run `flush privileges;`?

Comment: actually I miss that :/ how can I fix that since I'm basically locked out now?

Comment: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/

Comment: yeah I found that and I was trying to follow the steps but after `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &` I'm still not able to login without password `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`

Comment: running out of options.. there is a way I can safely delete `user` table and restart with a clean installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the problem, basically almost all the solution you can find around are **outdated**.
With mysql 8.0.15 you have to follow this guide
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

*I recommend to read the whole page*, but basically you have to use

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

**NOTE** Using the method `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string..` ***will lock you out from your own mysql server*** (you won't solve even with `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables`).
If you end up locked out, I guess the only hope (I didn't test it) is to stop `mysqld` and relaunch `mysqld` manually using `--init-file="myinitfile"` where `myinitfile` is a plain text file containing the `ALTER USER` instruction I mentioned before (I'm not sure it is even doable if you have installed `mysql` using `brew`, but note I'm new to macOS). Mine was a fresh installation, so I've just deleted the whole `/usr/local/var/mysql` directory and reinstalled mysql.

Comment: Please make sure to include the relevant parts of the linked page into your answer here, specifically the way to change passwords. I can image that this is a common problem, other users will benefit from finding the relevant information right here, without having to hope to another page and search for the answer there.

Comment: Even better would be an answer which also explains how to restore access once `UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string` was used.

Comment: edited the answer with more details